# Get Solrconfig components in java application using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I've set the default field for solr search in solrconfig.xml under requesthandler defaults.

`<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
          <int name="rows">10</int>
          <str name="df">text</str> 
      </lst>`

Is there anyway I can retrieve these values through solrj? Need this to implement multiple search domains dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure with Solrj, however you can can retrieve the Solr Config with direct http `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=solrConfig.xml`

Parse the xml file for the xml element.

Comment: Thanks. The approach is better than a file reading implementation. Will try this out